# Common Table Expressions - where do we create one at? View, Stored Proc, etc.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm very new to CTE's - when we define a common table expression, do we create it as a stored procedure, a view, etc.?  For example, if I have:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH DirectReports(ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, EmployeeLevel) AS 
(
    SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, 0 AS EmployeeLevel
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees 
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, EmployeeLevel + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
        INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID 
)
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, EmployeeLevel 
FROM DirectReports
ORDER BY ManagerID;
GO
```

Where would I store this?  I hope I'm making sense.  This is a query that I would like to store somewhere to be reused.

Comment: CTEs are always a *part* of an actual statement - in the above case, a `SELECT`. Your question is equivalent to "where should I create a `SELECT` statement?" - where obviously the answer is, wherever it makes sense for you to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a view. Although this is a hierarchical query, it still is just this: a query.